# Matching DateTimes in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm struggling with the PHP `DateTime` & `DateTimeZone` combo: What i want to achieve is, if current datetime matches a value in this format - "H:i" a block of PHP code to be executed. So far, i've managed to arrive at this "solution", however i'm struggling to make it work:

```
$datetime = new DateTime();
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Sofia');
$datetime->setTimezone($timezone);


if($datetime == '06:00') {
    DB::table('shifts')->insert(['shift_number' => '1', 'created_at' => $datetime, 'updated_at' => $datetime]);
}
```

I'm fairly new to PHP and i would greatly appreciate any help on the matter, thanks!

Comment: Looks like you compare `"H:i:s"` with `"H:i"`.

Comment: The point of `$firstShiftStart->format('H:i');` is to either output it or place it in a variable. So that line does nothing

Comment: @RiggsFolly got it. You are getting a match comparing the two objects but that isn't what you set out to do. Instead of the insert do `var_dump($datetime, $firstShiftStart);` to help debug it.

Comment: I have edited the code to more reflect what i'm trying to achieve, if you can please take a look at it again?

Comment: `if($datetime->format('H:i') == '06:00') {`

Comment: Between your two questions I think you could make an answer.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question, sir! If you so kindly post your answer, i'll gladly mark it!

Comment: @DanielO has posted pretty much what I would have posted, accept that answer instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format the dateTime object and then compare the formatted value.

Example:

```php
if($datetime->format('H:i') === '06:00') {
    echo 'match';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question, sir!